# Selecting multiple items in excel pivot table filter

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, vba

I am using vba to create a pivot table. The table has some filters and i am unable to select multiple items from the filter.

I recorded a macro and used the same functions as the system generated code but i am getting

```
"Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the CurrentPage Property of the PivotField Class"
```

Below is the code that is used to create the pivot table, which works:

```
Dim objTable As PivotTable
    Dim objField As PivotField

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("All Projects - iNexus").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard

    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Product")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("SPA Value Category")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2014 FY Value ($)")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("2015 FY Value ($)")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

    ActiveSheet.Name = "iNexus Pivot"

    ' Rename the pivot table
    With Sheets("iNexus Pivot")
        .PivotTables(1).Name = "PivotTable2"
    End With

    With Sheets("iNexus Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
    End With
```

THis is code that i got from the recorded macro to select multiple items from the recorded macro:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Project Status"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Project Status")
        .PivotItems("A").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("B").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Project Status"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```

Both CurrentPage and PivotItems seem to be the source of the problem, my vba skills are very limited and i am unable to debug the problem.

Thanks. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is the Project Status Field a `Report Filter` or a `Row Label` (or `Column Label`). The code is a bit different depending on which.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: In this particular case, it is a report filter, but i also have a column filter. I am assuming the difference between report, row and column is not too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and the solution is to include the filters while assigning an orientation using the following command:

```
objField.PivotItems("XXX").Visible = False
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162183/filtering-issues-with-macro-for-creating-pivot-table-in-excel-2010-vba?rq=1)

I found the logic from the below link.